# Data validation issue in MetroWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I'm really new to Wpf and I'm trying out various controls. I took this ViewModel from Metro Mahapps Demo and left only (assuming I didn't miss anything) the code which handles the data validation (number greater than 10) :

```
 public class Modelis : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    int? _integerGreater10Property;

    public Modelis(IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator)
    {    
    }
    public int? IntegerGreater10Property
    {
        get { return this._integerGreater10Property; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _integerGreater10Property))
            {
                return;
            }

            _integerGreater10Property = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IntegerGreater10Property");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the PropertyChanged event if needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that changed.</param>
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "IntegerGreater10Property" && this.IntegerGreater10Property < 10)
            {
                return "Number is not greater than 10";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Error { get { return string.Empty; } }
}
```

Then, I referenced it in my Window (also taken from the demo) :

```
         xmlns:Registracija="clr-namespace:Registracijos_sistema"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="600"
         d:DesignWidth="800"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Registracija:Modelis}"
```

But when I add a textbox (again from the demo) which notifies if number is not greater than 10, it doesn't seem to work:

```
        <TextBox   
        Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Number smaller than 10"
        Text="{Binding IntegerGreater10Property, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  
        Margin="104,197,47,104" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your MetroWindow xaml:

```
    xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
```

and do you have a dependency property in the code behind of your window, like this?

```
    public Modelis MyModelis
    {
        get { return (Modelis)GetValue(MyModelisProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyModelisProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyModelis.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyModelisProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyModelis", typeof(Modelis), typeof(Window1), new PropertyMetadata(new Modelis(DialogCoordinator.Instance)));
```

TIP: If you're using Visual Studio you can type propdp and hit 'TAB' to have it automatically add the code. Afterwards, just type in the missing values.

Then back in our MetroWindow xaml, change this:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Registracija:Modelis}"
```

to this:

```
 DataContext="{Binding MyModelis, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But can you explain why separate dependency property had to be created and d:DataContext didn't do the trick?

Comment: d:DataContext is a way to set the Design Time datacontext. So it would work, but only in the visual studio designer. setting DataContext is officially using that Object (that is exposed via the Dependency Property) as the datacontext for the form.